# WWW in address bar cause problem

Tags: database, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a silly question which drive me crazy. I have ASP programed website which when you use address like http://mysite.com/ it will work. If you use http://www.mysite.com/ it would not work. Basically when you use "www" in the beginning of the address the website will not function properly and specially login page will not work at all.

Any idea????

Comment: Do both mysite.com and www.mysite.com resolve to the DNS correctly?

Comment: I think "mysite" is a example, and not his actual site ?

Comment: What you mean "will not work at all"? Do you get error message? Blue screen of death? Unless you explain nobody can really help you.

Comment: You are right Elliott. mysite is an example. The real one is http://medallionrug.com

Comment: Shadow Wizard, when I said not working at all I meant in LOGIN page. That means no body can login when wwww is in address bar. The rest of the website is not working well. You can check out the website. http://medallionrug.com/

Comment: @Jay when replying to comment use `@` to notify otherwise you'll wait long days and nobody will see it. Anyway you still have to explain what you mean by "nobody can login" - what happens when you type correct user name and password? What error you get? What is the relevant code?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, when you have www in address bar you cant login and you get no error. Jut not working. Even tho you are loged in already when you type www in your address bar it immediately shows that you are not loged in. Give me your email so I email you an example. Even you can register and try your self to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: `www.mysite.com` and `mysite.com` are two different domains so they don't share the Session. Just login in both and it should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question belongs elsewhere, but here's something you can do.

Change your .htaccess file on the public_html folder of your website so you get a redirect from http://www.mysite.com to http://mysite.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} www\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.com/$1 [r=301,l]
```

If you use IIS, download the [URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/).
Modify the web.config file to include the following:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect from WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.mysite.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://mysite.com/{R:0}"
               redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is referred to as a "Canonical Redirect".

Comment: I havent seen .htaccess in any of my websites and basically I have no idea what it is. Would you kindly guide me where can if find this file/folder so I can change it?

Comment: @Jeff Lamb: -1. Jay might be using IIS, which doesn't support `.htaccess` files. IIS uses XML-based `Web.config` files.

Comment: @greyfade, you are right, Im using IIS. Would you tell me more about XML-Based Web.config? Thanks

Comment: @Jeff, That was very helpful. Do you think this kind of redirecting effect google crawler?

Comment: +1 It worked perfectly. But steel I don't know why my website is not functioning with www in the address bar.

Comment: @Jay In order to answer the 'why' question, we need more information or code or a link to your website from you.  I offered this up answer because I knew it'd work, and might make the real problem a non-issue.  As for google and search engines in general, they can adapt just fine.  This change consolidates your "2 websites" into one, and makes things better for search engine rankings and for reading site statistics if you use them.

Comment: @Jeff, The website is http://medallionrug.com/ if you want to check it out. But with redirecting in we.config my problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: Just a hunch, but `slogin()` has an iframe whose source is the non-www flavor of your website.  I bet if you change that to include `www.`, your site will break again.  Again, just a hunch, but if you have javascript going between that iframe and the parent frame, you'll probably get a cross-domain security issue.  You can verify by opening developer tools for chrome and looking at the errors that show up.  The real fix would be using relative pathing, or `location.href`, for your iframe.

Comment: Yep.  loginregister.asp has `onclick="parent.registerFormClose();` ... that'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Manager, make sure that the Website is set up to listen for both host headers.

IIS 6 Instructions:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/883a9544-3f70-4d46-a6df-bbadbd1fe7de.mspx?mfr=true

IIS 7 Instructions:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx